# awk | merge line on the basis of field matching

Tags: sed, awk

I need help with following:

Input file:

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
```

Output file:

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z, NOMATCH
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
```

Notes:

If you see in source file, for every "sent" message there is "receive"
only for session=342 there is no receive
session is unknow, can't be hardcoded
So merge only those sent and receive where we have matching session number

Comment: does the message=receive always follow the message=sent immediately, like this example?

Comment: not always.. if there is "message=sent" and "message=receive" for same session then only combine

Comment: also if you see then we have 2 message=sent (one after another) in an example, which means I need to skip one sent and continue with next line

Comment: do you have to awk and sed? Doing this in perl would be easy.  With awk and sed it could get ugly.

Comment: perl is also fine if it is not time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
awk -F "[:,]"  '/=sent/{a[$2]=$0;}/=receive/{print a[$2], $0;delete a[$2];}END{for(i in a)print a[i],"NO MATCH";}' file
```

Results:

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z NO MATCH
```

When the `send` record is encountered, it is store in the array with the session id as the index. When the `receive` record is encountered, the `send` record is fetched from the array and printed along with `receive` record. Also, sent records are removed from array as and when `receive` records are received. At the END,  all the remaining records in the array are printed as NO MATCH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.. but I am not able to understand the logic.. could you please explain it

Comment: Hello again Guru.. I have one more query.. is it possible to print output in a sequence in its order? for example NO MATCH should be print in between after session 123

Comment: If I'll reprase it then it should be like this: For every "=sent", search for "=receive" in **immediate** NEXT LINE ONLY for same session number<br/>So merge only those sent and receive where we have matching session number ELSE print the sent as it is in a sequence<br/>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
{
    x = $0

    gsub(/[^:]*:|,.*/,"")

    a[$0] = (a[$0] ? a[$0] "," FS : "") x
    b[$0]++
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        print (b[i] == 2 ? a[i] : a[i] "," FS "NOMATCH") | "sort"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z, NOMATCH
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z, pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '{ x = $0; gsub(/[^:]*:|,.*/,""); a[$0] = (a[$0] ? a[$0] "," FS : "") x; b[$0]++ } END { for (i in a) print (b[i] == 2 ? a[i] : a[i] "," FS "NOMATCH") | "sort" }' file
```

Note that you can drop the pipe to `sort` if you don't care about sorted output. HTH.

Comment: Hello Steve.. could you please explain the logic and why we are putting sort at the end?