# awk | merge consecutive 3 lines in a file on the basis of field matching

Tags: awk

**Input - file1.txt**

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
pqr message=receive session:123,4x,5x,7x
pqr message=receive session:123,4p,5q,7r
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z
abc message=receive session:311,x,y,z
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
```

**Output**

```
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z,pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z,pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7,pqr message=receive session:123,4x,5x,7x,pqr message=receive session:123,4p,5q,7r
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z,NOMATCH
abc message=receive session:311,x,y,z,NOMATCH
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
```

**Notes:**

1. Find sent and its immediate receive - for only MATCHING session number
2. Combine all session match "receive" with same "sent". For example: session:123
3. If no "receive" then print NOMATCH

Comment: Is it not the same question which you had asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847251/awk-merge-line-on-the-basis-of-field-matching

Comment: No.. This time we are trying to merge all lines on matching criteria.. previosuly we were merging only 2 lines. I know its kind of same but I tried to modify previous post but didnt succeeded.

Comment: @VipinChoudhary, why did you remove the `pqr` during the first merge but not the others?

Comment: Sorry.. That was typo.. correcting now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F "[:,]"  '{split($2,a,",");if($1~/sent/){if(prev!~/receive/&& NR!=1)print prev,"NOMATCH";else if (NR!=1)print prev;prev=$0;session=a[1];}if($1~/receive/&&session==a[1]){prev=prev","$0;}}'END'{if(prev~/receive/)print prev;}' file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Gopal.. But Output differ.. last record is somehow missed

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{x=substr($3,0,match($3,","));a[x]?a[x]=a[x]","$0:a[x]=$0}END{for(i in a){print a[i],a[i]~/sent/&&a[i]~/receive/?"":"NOMATCH"}}' your_file
```

tested:

```
>cat temp
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7
pqr message=receive session:123,4x,5x,7x
pqr message=receive session:123,4p,5q,7r
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z
abc message=receive session:311,x,y,z
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z
pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7
> 
> 
> 
> awk '{x=substr($3,0,match($3,","));a[x]?a[x]=a[x]","$0:a[x]=$0}END{for(i in a){print a[i],a[i]~/sent/&&a[i]~/receive/?"":"NOMATCH"}}' temp
abc message=sent session:111,x,y,z,pqr message=receive session:111,4,5,7 
abc message=sent session:123,x,y,z,pqr message=receive session:123,4,5,7,pqr message=receive session:123,4x,5x,7x,pqr message=receive session:123,4p,5q,7r 
abc message=receive session:311,x,y,z NOMATCH
abc message=sent session:589,x,y,z,pqr message=receive session:589,4,5,7 
abc message=sent session:342,x,y,z NOMATCH
>
```