# Command line to match lines with matching first field (sed, awk, etc.)

Tags: regex, sed, awk

What is fast and succinct way to match lines from a text file with a matching first field.

Sample input:

```
a|lorem
b|ipsum
b|dolor
c|sit
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit
```

Desired output:

```
b|ipsum
b|dolor
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit
```

Desired output, alternative:

```
b|ipsum|dolor
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
```

I can imagine many ways to write this, but I suspect there's a smart way to do it, e.g., with sed, awk, etc. My source file is approx 0.5 GB.

There are some related questions here, e.g., "[awk | merge line on the basis of field matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847251/awk-merge-line-on-the-basis-of-field-matching)", but that other question loads too much content into memory. I need a streaming method.

Comment: Explain WHY that's the desired output as it's not obvious at all. e.g. are you looking for a tool that will let you specify b, d, and e as desirable key values or are you looking for cases where the key appears twice in the input or something else?

Comment: I want to merge lines with a matching first field. Sorry this was unclear. Also, the input is sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method where you only have to remember the previous line (therefore requires the input file to be sorted)

```
awk -F \| '
    $1 == prev_key {print prev_line; matches ++}
    $1 != prev_key {                            
        if (matches) print prev_line
        matches = 0
        prev_key = $1
    }                
    {prev_line = $0}
    END { if (matches) print $0 }
' filename
```

```
b|ipsum
b|dolor
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit
```

Alternate output

```
awk -F \| '
    $1 == prev_key {
        if (matches == 0) printf "%s", $1 
        printf "%s%s", FS, prev_value
        matches ++
    }             
    $1 != prev_key {
        if (matches) printf "%s%s\n", FS, prev_value
        matches = 0                                 
        prev_key = $1
    }                
    {prev_value = $2}
    END {if (matches) printf "%s%s\n", FS, $2}
' filename
```

```
b|ipsum|dolor
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
```

Comment: But how can OP get `Desired output, alternative`?

Comment: Your method works nicely, 0m16.330s processing. time awk -F \| '$1 == prev_key {print prev_line; matches ++} $1 != prev_key { if (matches) print prev_line; matches = 0; prev_key = $1; } {prev_line = $0} END { if (matches) print $0 } ' INFILE > OUTFILE

Answer (score 3):

For fixed width fields you can used `uniq`:

```
$ uniq -Dw 1 file
b|ipsum
b|dolor
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit
```

---

If you don't have fixed width fields here are two `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=(b[$1])?b[$1]RS$0:$0}END{for(k in a)if(a[k]>1)print b[k]}' file
b|ipsum
b|dolor
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit

awk -F'|' '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=b[$1]FS$2}END{for(k in a)if(a[k]>1)print k b[k]}' file
b|ipsum|dolor
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
```

Comment: Thanks. The second field is an unpredictable length, often >100 chars. btw, those arguments for "uniq" are not available in MacOS, nor Ubuntu.

Comment: Fair enough, the two `awk` scripts should do the trick for you. Are you sure they are not available on your Ubuntu machine? What version of coreutils do you have. `uniq --version - uniq (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Comment: Thanks! The second is really what I need. Your methods work well; 0m29.103s processing for the first, and 0m34.036s for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '|' '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{b[$1]=b[$1] FS a[$1] FS $2}
    END{for(i in b) print i b[i]}' file
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
b|ipsum|dolor
```

Comment: Would have high memory requirement when the input file is large

Comment: My concern about awk was loading everything into memory, then recalling it in the END; but my concerns might be unwarranted. I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: To my surprise, your method works on my 0.5GB input file. 0m19.184s processing time.  time awk -F '|' '!($1 in a){a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{b[$1]=b[$1] FS a[$1] FS $2} END{for(i in b) print i b[i]}'  INFILE > OUTFILE

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^(([^|]*\|).*)\n\2/\1|/;ta;/^([^\n|]*\|){2,}/P;D' /file
```

This reads 2 lines into the pattern space then checks to see if the keys in both lines are the same. If so it removes the second key and repeats. If not it checks to see if more than two fields exist in the first line and if so prints it out and then deletes it otherwise it just deletes the first line.

Comment: Thanks for this. I already used the awk, but it's useful having a sed solution.

Comment: Note, on the mac, "sed -r" is "sed -E"; also note that your method did not work for me, at least on my mac, with the above test content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 == prev {rec = rec RS $0; size++; next} {if (size>1) print rec; rec=$0; size=1} {prev = $1} END{if (size>1) print rec}' file
b|ipsum
b|dolor
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit

$ awk -F'|' '$1 == prev {rec = rec FS $2; size++; next} {if (size>1) print rec; rec=$0; size=1} {prev = $1} END{if (size>1) print rec}' file
b|ipsum|dolor
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
```

Comment: I tried your second method. It's fast, but I got some false hits. Thanks for the sample though.

Comment: False hits? Hard to believe if your real input looks like your sample input but if you'd care to share what your input was and the undesirable output you got, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Ed, I don't mean to criticize, and the error might be on my side. All I can say is that when I ran a quick test, the output was not what I expected. My input is substantially more complex than the sample I gave, but still basically the same idea of 2 fields separated by a pipe. I don't think there's any need to delve into this more. Thanks again.