# Command line to remove in-line dupes

Tags: regex, awk, sed, command-line-interface

What is fast and succinct way to remove dupes from within a line?

I have a file in the following format:

```
alpha • a | b | c | a | b | c | d
beta • h | i | i | h | i | j | k
gamma •  m | n | o
delta • p | p | q | r | s | q
```

So there's a headword in column 1, and then various words delimited by pipes, with an unpredictable amount of duplication. The desired output has the dupes removed, as:

```
alpha • a | b | c | d
beta • h | i | j | k
gamma •  m | n | o
delta • p | q | r | s
```

My input file is a few thousand lines. The Greek names above correspond to category names (e.g., "baseball"); and the alphabet corresponds English dictionary words (which might contain spaces or accents), e.g. "ball game | batter | catcher | catcher | designated hitter".

This could be programmed many ways, but I suspect there's a smart way to do it. I encounter variations of this scenario a lot, and wonder if there's a concise and elegant way to do this. I am using MacOS, so a few fancy unix options are not available.

Bonus complexity, I often have a comment at the end which should be retained, e.g.,

```
zeta • x | y | x | z | z ; comment here
```

*P.S. this input is actually the output of a prior StackOverflow question: 
[Command line to match lines with matching first field (sed, awk, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493326/command-line-to-match-lines-with-matching-first-field-sed-awk-etc)*

Comment: So you have three delimiters, the middle dot or bullet, the pipes, and (sometimes) a semicolon.  Do these symbols ever appear except as delimiters?  Is it crucial that the names are in alphabetic order after being uniquified?

Comment: My example happens to be sorted, but the real input is not sorted. Those three delimiters (•,|,;) ONLY appear in the field delimiters. The order of the output is flexible (could be same as input or sorted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSD `awk` does not have `sort` functions builtin where GNU `awk` does, but I'm not sure they're necessary.  The bullet, • (U+2022), causes some grief with `awk`.

I suggest pre-processing the bullet to a single-byte character.  I chose `@`, but you could use <kbd>Control-A</kbd> or something else if you prefer.  Your data was in a file `data`.  I note that there was a double space before `m` in the `gamma` line; I'm assuming that isn't significant.

```
sed 's/•/@/' data |
awk -F ' *[@|] *' '
{
    delete names
    delete comments
    delete fields;
    if ($NF ~ / *;/) { split($NF, comments, / *; */); $NF=comments[1]; }
    j = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        if (names[$i]++ == 0)
            fields[j++] = $i;
    }
    printf("%s", $1);
    delim = "•"
    for (k = 1; k < j; k++)
    {
        printf(" %s %s", delim, fields[k]);
        delim = "|";
    }
    if (comments[2])
        printf(" ; %s", comments[2]);
    printf("\n");
}'
```

Running this yields:

```
alpha • a | b | c | d
beta • h | i | j | k
gamma • m | n | o
delta • p | q | r | s
zeta • x | y | z ; comment here
```

Comment: Appears to work great, thanks! I changed my first delimiter to a "@", omitting the need for the sed. Maybe it's not a one-liner, but it's clean and better than a more complex little program I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

With bash, sort, xargs, sed:

```
while IFS='•;' read -r a b c; do
  IFS="|" read -ra array <<< "$b"
  array=( "${array[@]# }" )
  array=( "${array[@]% }" )
  readarray -t array < <(printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" | sort -zu | xargs -0n1)
  SAVE_IFS="$IFS"; IFS="|"
  s="$a• ${array[*]}"
  [[ $c != "" ]] && s="$s ;$c"
  sed 's/|/ | /g' <<< "$s"
  IFS="$SAVE_IFS"
done < file
```

Output:

```
alpha • a | b | c | d
beta • h | i | j | k
gamma •  m | n | o
delta • p | q | r | s
zeta • x | y | z ; comment here
```

I suppose the two spaces before "m" are a typo.

Comment: yeah, the 2 spaces before the "m" are a typo, and I could clean my content to exactly match my demo.

Comment: Thanks for writing this. I'm always a little afraid of straight bash scripts in case there's something wrong with my input and I accidentally rm -r /. I didn't test it, since the answer from Jonathan works, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  'h;s/.*• \([^;]*\).*/cat <<\\! | sort -u |\1|!/;s/\s*|\s*/\n/2ge;s/\n/ | /g;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*• \)[^;]*/\2\1/;s/;/ &/' file
```

The sketch of this idea is: to remove the head and tail of each line, morph the data into a mini file, use standard utilities to sort and remove duplicates, then put the line back together again.

Here a copy of the line is held in the hold space. The id and comments removed. The data is munged into a file using cat and the bash here-document syntax and piped through a sort (and uniq if your sort does not come equipped with the `-u` option). The pattern space is evaluated and the line reassembled by appending the original line to the pattern space and using regexp pattern matching.