# Command line to merge lines with matching first field, 50 GB input

Tags: regex, optimization, awk, sed

A while back, I asked a question about merging lines which have a common first field. Here's the original: [Command line to match lines with matching first field (sed, awk, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493326/command-line-to-match-lines-with-matching-first-field-sed-awk-etc)

Sample input:

```
a|lorem
b|ipsum
b|dolor
c|sit
d|amet
d|consectetur
e|adipisicing
e|elit
```

Desired output:

```
b|ipsum|dolor
d|amet|consectetur
e|adipisicing|elit
```

The idea is that if the first field matches, then the lines are merged. The input is sorted. The actual content is more complex, but uses the pipe as the sole delimiter.

The methods provided in the prior question worked well on my 0.5GB file, processing in ~16 seconds. However, my new file is approx 100x larger, and I prefer a method that streams. In theory, this will be able to run in ~30 minutes. The prior method failed to complete after running 24 hours.

Running on MacOS (i.e., BSD-type unix).

Ideas? [Note, the prior answer to the prior question was NOT a one-liner.]

Comment: The accepted answer in the previous question streams. I'm not sure I could improve it much.

Comment: In your last question you reported that you had an inexplicably undesirable result when you ran the script I posted (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18494009/1745001) and chalked it up to the data being more complex than what you had posted. Did you figure out what exactly was causing the problem? If not, not much point trying to tackle this one when we don't know what caused the last one to fail.

Comment: You could try to join the file with himself and than filter out rows with duplicated values: join -1 1 -2 1 -t '|' test.txt test.txt (works only if the row with common first field are 2)

Comment: BTW I'll suggest to use a scripting language, read the input one line at a time and build the input one line at a time.

Comment: In order to better optimize, answer some questions of the data such as: Is there a maximum number of lines between any two duplicates?  Can there be more than two duplicates?  Also, `mawk` is a version of `awk` optimized for speed, so using that should improve performance on a big file.

Comment: max lines between two duplicates - unknown, but probably around 1k; more than 2 duplicates - absolutely, often dozens.

Comment: Hi Barmar -- Ha!... you are right. The multiline script (which I had accepted as the answer) does stream. I was using this one, since it was concise, which does not stream: awk -F'|' '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=b[$1]FS$2}END{for(k in a)if(a[k]>1)print k b[k]}' ... I don't really understand why the latter does not.

Comment: Based on that last comment from @MichaelDouma, this question is a duplicate of [Command line to match lines with matching first field (sed, awk, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493326/command-line-to-match-lines-with-matching-first-field-sed-awk-etc)

Comment: @MichaelDouma hey Michael, I might be missing something, but I think my answer will be a lot simpler and it bypasses checking results in the `END` statement. The only issue would be if you want the new concatenated results in one big file rather than separate files, although `cat *little_files > one_big_file` would solve that.

Comment: Hi Adam, No it technically isn't, since the 'solution' in the old question was not a one-liner.

Comment: @MichaelDouma any `awk` program is a one liner if you want it to be ;)

Comment: @isosceleswheel, I don't (currently) need to process multiple files, and `cat` would solve that anyway as you note.

Comment: @MichaelDouma no but if you use my command you will create a file for each of the indices so if you want to re-create a 50GB result file you would need to use this extra step.

Comment: @Barmar what does "stream" mean in this context? Does that just refer to not storing lots of data during the processing?

Comment: @isosceleswheel That's how I interpreted it. In particular, the memory usage is not a function of the total length of the input.

Comment: @Barmar - By "stream" I meant that it immediately starts to return output, either to stout or that could be tailed on the > output file. Also, as you note that memory does not depend on the file size.

Comment: @MichaelDouma That's how I would have normally interpreted it, but I thought you might have meant something else because you accepted the streaming answer. That was before you added the comment here admitting that you were using a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can append you results to a file on the fly so that you don't need to build a 50GB array (which I assume you don't have the memory for!). This command will concatenate the join fields for each of the different indices in a string which is written to a file named after the respective index with some suffix.

**EDIT:** on the basis of OP's comment that content may have spaces, I would suggest using `-F"|"` instead of `sub` and also the following answer is designed to write to standard out

**(New) Code:**

```
# split the file on the pipe using -F
# if index "i" is still $1 (and i exists) concatenate the string
# if index "i" is not $1 or doesn't exist yet, print current a
# (will be a single blank line for first line)
# afterwards, this will print the concatenated data for the last index
# reset a for the new index and take the first data set
# set i to $1 each time
# END statement to print the single last string "a"
awk -F"|" '$1==i{a=a"|"$2}$1!=i{print a; a=$2}{i=$1}END{print a}'
```

This builds a string of "data" while in a given index and then prints it out when index changes and starts building the next string on the new index until that one ends... repeat...

Comment: Thanks. My content is more complex, and could have spaces before or after the pipe delimiter. I would process only one file. Any adjustments you might have are welcome.

Comment: @MichaelDouma I see, well in that case the -F"|" should work and you can just drop the `sub` command I think... assuming there aren't OTHER pipes in the content later?

Comment: Can you write that in code so I am sure I get it right? I'll test it against my file, and report the speed vs. the larger non-one-liner.

Comment: @MichaelDouma I updated the post. Basically remove `sub` completely and use `-F` as suggested by others.

Comment: thx! Will try it in a few minutes after the non-one-liner is done so I can semi-accurately compare speeds.

Comment: Sure! I'm curious to know how the two methods stack up.

Comment: @MichaelDouma also one consideration is how you want to format the "results" that are concatenated, i.e. `a|X\nb|Y\na|Z` gives `a|XZ` and  `b|Y` in my command, so you might want to add a delimiter e.g. `printf("%s<DELIMITER>", $2)`

Comment: What am I doing wrong with `cat tmp1 | awk -F"|" '{s=sprintf("%s", $1"SUFFIX"); printf("%s | ", $2) >> s; close(s)}' | head` which results with: *awk: can't open file*

Comment: The file is closed. The command I posted writes to files, I doesn't produce any standard output.

Comment: Try this mini-example to see expected output: `echo -e "abc|tt hh 56\ndef|rtr 6\nabc|OK" | awk -F"|" '{ s=sprintf("%s", $1".txt"); printf("%s ", $2) >> s; close(s)}'` it should produce two files called "abc.txt" and "def.txt"

Comment: If you are interested, can you adapt this for stdin/out? I use this as part of a much longer series of pipes with sed, other awks, to extract data from a JSON file, and I process the output much more.

Comment: I see your mini example. That does not help, unfortunately. The nature of my 50GB file is that it would make WAY too many subfiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84732/discussion-between-isosceleswheel-and-michael-douma).

Comment: output is not corresponding to OP, "joined" lines with only 1 argument are filtered and here are printed (and missing first element). Not too hard to adapt but need some more line of code

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '# label anchor for a jump
   :loop
# load a new line in working buffer (so always 2 lines loaded after)
   N
# verify if the 2 lines have same starting pattern and join if the case
   /^\(\([^|]\)*\(|.*\)\)\n\2/ s//\1/
# if end of file quit (and print result)
   $ b
# if lines are joined, cycle and re make with next line (jump to :loop)
   t loop
# (No joined lines here)
# if more than 2 element on first line, print first line
   /.*|.*|.*\n/ P
# remove first line (using last search pattern)
   s///
# (if anay modif) cycle (jump to :loop)
   t loop
# exit and print working buffer
   ' YourFile
```

- posix version (maybe --posix on Mac)
- self commented
- assume sorted entry, no empty line, no pipe in data (nor escaped one)
- used unbufferd `-u` for a stream process if available