# join all lines that have the same first column to the same line

Tags: sorting, unix, join, sed

IE:

File:

```
1234:abcd  
1234:930  
1234:999999  
194:keee  
194:284  
194:222222
```

Result:

```
1234:abcd:930:999999  
194:kee:284:222222
```

I have exhausted my brain to the best of my knowledge and can't come up with a way. Sorry to bother you guys!

Comment: Can you use some scripting language like python, if u have huge file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line to merge lines with matching first field, 50 GB input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729187/command-line-to-merge-lines-with-matching-first-field-50-gb-input)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F: '$1==last {printf ":%s",$2; next} NR>1 {print "";} {last=$1; printf "%s",$0;} END{print "";}' file
1234:abcd:930:999999
194:keee:284:222222
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This tells `awk` to use a `:` as the field separator.
- `$1==last {printf ":%s",$2; next}`

  If the first field of this line is the same as the first field of the last line, print a colon followed by field 2.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and start over with the next line.
- `NR>1 {print "";}`

  If we get here, that means that this line has a new not-seen-before value of the first field.  If this not the first line, we finish the last line by printing a newline character.
- `{last=$1; printf "%s",$0;}`

  Update the variable `last` with the new value of field 1.  Then, print this line.
- `END{print "";}`

  After we reach the end of the file, print one last newline character.

#### Combining non-consecutive lines

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat testfile2
3:abcd
4:abcd
10:123
3:999
4:999
10:123
```

Apply this awk script:

```
$ awk -F: '{a[$1]=a[$1]":"$2;} END{for (x in a) print x ":" substr(a[x],2);}' testfile2
3:abcd:999
4:abcd:999
10:123:123
```

In this approach, the lines will not necessarily come out in any particular order.  If order is important, you may want to pipe this output to `sort`.

Comment: Hm. On a test this works like for the text above, but for some reason on the real file (about 2 million lines the same) it doesn't do anything. The output file is the EXACT same as input. Weird?

Comment: 3:abcd
4:abcd
5:abcd
6:abcd
7:abcd
8:abcd
9:abcd
10:123
11:abcd
12:abcd
13:abcd
14:abcd
15:abcd
16:abcd
17:abcd
18:abcd
19:abcd
20:abcd
3:999
4:999
5:999
6:999
7:999
8:999
9:999
10:123
11:999
12:999
13:999
14:999
15:999
16:999
17:999
18:999
19:999
20:999

Comment: See on that it does not work, any ideas? Sorry for the mess

Comment: For your new file, `3:abcd 4:abcd 5:abcd...`, and unlike the sample data in the question, each line has a first column different from the line before.  That is why the code changes nothing.  Did you want to combine lines even if they aren't consecutive lines with the same first column?

Comment: @jahill2002 I just added to the answer a method for combining non-consecutive lines.