# AWK:Convert columns to rows with condition (create list )

Tags: awk, printf, uniq

I have File 1 (tab delimited):

```
ALI 1987 
ALI 2015 
ADAM 368 
ADAM 659 
JILL 123c.56 
JILL 78p.rs_896
```

And I would like to get File2:

```
ALI: 1987, 2015
ADAM: 368,659
JILL: 123c.56, 78p.rs_896
```

I know how to revert columns to rows only for $2:

```
awk '{printf ("%s,",$2)}' File1
```

But How could I create condition for $1 only uniqe first?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join lines with the same value in the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823941/join-lines-with-the-same-value-in-the-first-column), or [join all lines that have the same first column to the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623035/join-all-lines-that-have-the-same-first-column-to-the-same-line)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/0XVbJT, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623035/join-all-lines-that-have-the-same-first-column-to-the-same-line)